# Linq one to many (parent and child entities) using criteria on child entity

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have three entities

```
Form
 FormProducts (one to Many attach to Form)
 FormFields (one to Many attach to Form)
```

When I get Form (using below code), FormProducts and FormFields are implicitly attached to form, which is what we require.

```
Form result = Forms.Where(f => f.Code == "form1").FirstOrDefault()
```

So far so good, But new requirement came in that we also need to check product criteria for active products.

Is there a simple way of doing it? or should I have to explicity use join with all three entities.

I am looking something like that simple :)

```
Form result = Forms.Where(f => f.Code == "form1" && f.FormProducts.status == "active").FirstOrDefault()
```

**UPDATE:**
Sorry If I have not made myself clear, 
consider following data in tables

```
Form 
id, code(unique)
1, form1, 
2, form2
3, form3

FormProduct
id, formid, name, status
1, 1, prod1, true
2, 1, prod2, false
3, 1, prod3, true

FormField
id, formid, name
1, 1, field1
2, 1, field1
3, 1, field1
```

I like to get form1 and its all formFields and all active formProducts. Which means Prod2 should not be included.

Comment: You cannot filter children: if a parent is included, all its children must be included as well.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight What is the best way to achieve it?

Comment: You can use condition on inner query. Forms.Where(f => f.Code == "form1" && f.FormProducts.Any(p => p.status == "active")).FirstOrDefault()

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is best way to achieve it, but that is how I impliment it for time being till I find better way.

```
Form result = Forms.Where(f => f.Code == "form1").FirstOrDefault()
result.FormProducts = result.FormProducts.Where(f.FormProducts.status == "active").ToList();
```